# How to selectively hide elements in HTML/CSS based on window size without using media queries?

Tags: html, css, frontend

I want to create a toolbar using HTML/CSS where certain elements disappear entirely when the browser size is reduced. It should be similar to how the favorites bar works on most browsers, displaying a variable number of items.

In this example, the flex item for section 2 should hide when the browser size causes it to be reduced below its original width of 300px. At the moment, it shrinks rather than disappearing. I want this behavior to be responsive based on the item's size, so I don't think that media queries will work. Is selective hiding of elements achievable using CSS?

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/MatthewBall/q7whe863/)

CSS:

```
...

.container{
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    border: 2px black solid;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

div{
    height: 100px;
}

#div1{
    width: 300px;
    background-color:#7fffd4;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

#div2{
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #ffb6c1;
}
```

HTML:

```
...
<body>
    <container class="container">
        <div id="div1">Section 1: this section should always remain visible</div>
        <div id="div2">Section 2: this entire section should disappear when reduced below initial width of 300px</div>
    </container>
</body>
```

Comment: CSS Media Queries works based on size of the viewport, e.g. `@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {`

Answer (score 1):

The method you are looking for is the new css container query, based in it parent's size to change

https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Container_Queries

Also there is a javascript way to do exact same as media query: javascript match media method (not like above container query)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

Comment: Thanks for making me aware of this. However, one problem I had is that an item with flex-shrink set to zero will not disappear based on this criteria, even when partially obscured.

Comment: In the end, I came to a solution without using the container query by using wrapping, non-shrinking items inside a container of the same height. This obscures them totally and creates a nice effect for any number of contained items of any size.

Link: https://jsfiddle.net/MatthewBall/nfh2q6xp/7/